# PhoneGap sendEmail

Tags: phonegap-plugins

How can I send email to any email address e.g (gmail, yahoo, etc.) in PhoneGap Application 
or by use of Java Script.

I am using the following links to use the android_PhoneGap plugin in order to send the mail but i am not successful.

Link: http://smus.com/android-phonegap-plugins#comment-184910636.

I am following the given instructions on this link but it doesn't work and returns this error: "Failed to send email via Android Intent"

I hanged to solve this problem.

Please Help ...

Thanks

Comment: Which version of PhoneGap? if 2.1.0 or above, did you added plugin to your config.xml ? (res/xml/config.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually update your Android's manifest file allowing it to send emails?

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
```

Any more detailed error logs would help as well!

Comment: here's also a [plugin](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/EmailComposer) that will help you do that...